# STL exceptions are not thrown Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

This code should definitely throw "vector subscript out of range" exception with a pop-up dialog.
But absolutely nothing happens.

```
std::vector<int> x;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    x.pop_back();
```

I tried enabling C++ exceptions through `Debug->Windows->Exception Settings` but it didn't help ...

What could cause this ??

Why exceptions are disabled in Visual studio 2015 ?

**Edit**:
My question remains the same but for this code:

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::cout << x.at(3) << '\n';
```

**Edit 2** Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    x.at(3) = 123;
    return 0;
}
```

nothing thrown, but [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) says it should throw

Comment: Can't see that [`pop_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) is supposed to throw anything. The reference says "Exceptions: (none)".

Comment: And [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) clearly states it causes UB if the vector is empty.

Comment: @BoPersson my question is not about pop_back(). It is a general question. Even when I do ` std::vector<int> x;
 std::cout << x[3] << '\n';` it does not throw anything

Comment: @ampawd It doesn't throw because the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I know that this case is 100% UB. But even doing ` std::vector<int> x;
 std::cout << x.at(3) << '\n';`  does not throw anything. `at` should of throw in this case

Comment: @ampawd Post some compilable code that illustrates `at`  not throwing.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ok

Comment: @NeilButterworth updated

Comment: That  does not illustrate `at` not throwing - do do that you would need suitable try/catch blocks in your code. And the code is not compilable.

Comment: The `at(3)` throws an exception for me. Can you post the whole code that doesn't throw?

Comment: @Galik there are nothing special in the full code, but anyway ...

Comment: The code you posted throws fine for me. Can you create a **complete** program incorporating **only** those two lines (and the necessary #includes) and it **not** throw an exception?

Comment: @Galik done. Please check it

Comment: Thanks. Well that code gives me a `std::out_of_range` exception. Maybe your compiler has a bug?

Comment: @Galik I'm not sure how to check that

Comment: @ampawd It may seem "picky" but it is important to provide the full code to create the error to rule out other bad code possibly causing a memory corruption. Those things can affect (apparently) unrelated code. So bad code somewhere else can affect perfectly good code.

Comment: @ampawd You still haven't added try/catch blocks to your code. And are you sure this is the code you are executing? Add a print statement before the putative invalid access to make sure.

Comment: @NeilButterworth yes that is the code I'm executing. Tried with `try catch` and exception was thrown but only to the console. What I was expecting is dialog box runtime exception without `try catch`.

Comment: I have compiled your code with VS 2015 Community and it definitely throws. At runtime you should get a dialog saying that abort() has been called, which is what not catching exceptions does.

Comment: @NeilButterworth yes thats the thing. I wanted to know why that runtime dialog box is not appearing at all...

Comment: "that runtime dialog box" is a question about the interaction between C++ programs that throw exceptions and Windows. To see whether an exception is being thrown, catch it. Once you've determined that the exception is being thrown, you can try to figure out why the **Windows** runtime mechanism isn't telling you that that happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is building with a different runtime library for linking.

Solution:
C/C++ -> Code Generation-> Runtime Library : changed to Multi-threaded Debug(/MTd)

Answer (score 2):

Why does `pop_back` must throw exception？

> Calling pop_back on an empty container is undefined.

So it's an **Undefined behavior**. Of course it needn't throw.

Answer (score 0):

There is a price to pay for `C++` being *fast* and that means not everything can be checked at run-time. Expecially in loops a check on every access would slow things down.

You can use *debug* versions of the library (if the compiler supports them) and those should complain about bad accesses. Otherwise some compilers support memory checking flags to detect out of bounds accesses at compile time.

You can (and I would suggest should) check boundaries using `assert()` (or similar) which only checks debug builds and has a zero cost in the release version.